# PHP loop in object

Tags: php, object, loops

I have 4 instances of the same object:

```
echo $payment->field_course_1_length[0]['value'];
echo $payment->field_course_2_length[0]['value'];
echo $payment->field_course_3_length[0]['value'];
echo $payment->field_course_4_length[0]['value'];
```

My question is so that I don't have to be typing the same over and over can I put it in a loop like this:

```
for ($i=1; $i<5; $i++) {

echo $payment->field_course_'$i'_length[0]['value'];

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but syntax is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
 for($i = 1;  $i <= 4; $i++) {
     echo $payment->{"field_course_".$i."_length"}[0]['value'];
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $payment->{"field_course_{$i}_length"}[0]['value'];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$tmp = $payment->{'field_course_' . $i . '_length'};
echo $tmp[0]['value'];
```

However, I strongly recommend to use arrays instead of dynamic properties. If they are not dynamic, don't access them dynamic.